# Sending FormData with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, form-data

I'm currently doing some exercises in order to learn API get/post requests.

I'm making a POST request to http://aq-test.000webhostapp.com/v1/user/new  and I have to send this as parameters:

```
formdata: [
  { "key": "name", "description": "User Name", "type": "text" },
  { "key": "charge", "description": "Position", "type": "text"},
  { "key": "email", "description": "User Email", "type": "text" },
  { "key": "password", "description": "User Password", "type": "text" }
]
```

I'm doing this request using AngularJS, this way:

```
var form = new FormData();

form.append('name', 'John Doe');
form.append('charge', 'Dev');
form.append('email', 'x@x.com');
form.append('password', 'pwd');

return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url + 'user/new',
    data: form,
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

The problem is that, when making this request, the data is sent like this:

```
[------WebKitFormBoundaryAial7t7Qm5B8KQMv
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "name"

John Doe
------WebKitFormBoundaryAial7t7Qm5B8KQMv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="charge"

Dev
------WebKitFormBoundaryAial7t7Qm5B8KQMv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

x@x.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryAial7t7Qm5B8KQMv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

pwd
------WebKitFormBoundaryAial7t7Qm5B8KQMv--
```

And the service answer is: (form field 'name' not valid)

```
{"status":false,"message":"Campo 'name' no v\u00e1lidoo."}
```

What am I doing wrong here? PostMan's request body's sent data works flawlessly, and looks different to mine.

```
[name] => John Doe
[charge] => Dev
[email] => x@x.com
[password] => pwd
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Share with us how is the API expecting the request (does the API provider specifie any guideline for doing requests?). What's different from the Postman request from yours? (headers, etc)

Comment: It is wiser to POST data like this as `application/json`. The [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) should only be used with legacy server APIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot to @georgeawg, for pointing me in the right direction. I had to set the Content-Type to undefined.

Comment: When posting objects created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it is important to set the `Content-type` header to `undefined`.